How to customize output file extension as "*.cp39-win_amd64.pyd" when creating a pybind11 python module with VS?
I'm trying to create a Pybind11 Python module (exactly a .dll file) called CAVSim with Visual Studio 2022.
I can simply make VS output a file named CAVSim.pyd by configuring Advanced-Target File Extension as .pyd.
Now I want to output file with name like CAVSim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd to differ modules for different version of python when uploading them to GitHub.
But when I set the Advanced-Target File Extension of the project property to .cp39-win_amd64.pyd, I got warnings like this in compiling:
1>...\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1393,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.cp39-win_amd64.pyd) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (.pyd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>...\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1394,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(CAVSim) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (CAVSim.cp39-win_amd64). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

Also I've tried changing Linker-General-Output File as $(OutDir)$(TargetName).$(CPythonVersion)-win_$(ProcessorArchitecture)$(TargetExt) instead, but got similar warnings.
The binary files generated after the warnings has correct file name and works right. So I think the configuration above are to some extend RIGHT, BUT NOT PROPER.
My question is, how can I configure the project PROPERLY, to get the right output file name CAVSim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd without accepting the warnings above?

Rename it with a shell command in a post-build step?
